# Update TextView with each string in String-array every 5 seconds

Tags: android, arrays, string, countdowntimer

I have a `TextView` and I would like to update the `TextView` every 5 second with each string in my String Array.

Here is the code I tried. It always shows only the last String in the String array.

```
TextView display;
EditText caption;
Thread thread;
String blinks;
String[] wc;
private CountDownTimer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    caption = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caption);

    timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 20) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            String[] wc = {"The","Qucik", "Brown","fox","Jumped"};
            for (int j = 0; j < wc.length; j++) {

                blinks = wc[j];
                final String[] titles = {"" + blinks + ""};

                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    display.setText(titles[i]);
                }

            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            try{
                yourMethod();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: it is much simpler to use Handler for this
look at this 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/13423036/1531683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
final String[] wc = {"The", "Qucik", "Brown", "fox", "Jumped"};
        final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            int i = 0;

            @Override
            public void run() {
                display.setText(wc[i]);
                i++;
                if (i == wc.length) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                } else {
                    //5 sec
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 5);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you make it loop infinitely?

Comment: To make it loop infinitely, just reset the counter as in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31493912/913286): `display.setText(wc[i++]); if (i == wc.length) { i = 0; }  handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

try to play Around with handler in android , i think you are asing something like this :

```
String[] wc = {"The","Qucik", "Brown","fox","Jumped"};
int j = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable runit = new Runnable() { 

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
     try{

            for (; j < wc.length; j++) {

                blinks = wc[j];
                final String[] titles = {"" + blinks + ""};

                for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
                    display.setText(titles[i]);
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this,5000);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //  handle exception
        }
    } 
}; 
handler.postDelayed(runit, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Problem: The last iteration of the for-loop (on j) sets the text to the last string.

You need to make sure that you call `TextView.setText()` only once per tick. Then you can go with your approach (`CountDownTimer`) or with [Antrrommet's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31493878/913286) (`Handler`). With your approach, this will look like something like:

```
int counter = 0; // field member, NOT local variable

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    display.setText("{" + wc[counter++] + "}");
    if (counter == 5) counter = 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is useful. Please do vote :)

```
        final String[] gritArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gritInformation);
    //creating new handler allows send and process message
        final Handler gritInfoHanlder = new Handler();
    //adding runnable to message queque
            gritInfoHanlder.post(new Runnable() {
    //initializing array position
                int tipPosition = 0;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //set number of tip(randon/another way)
//setting array to textview
                    gritInfo.setText(gritArray[tipPosition]);
                    tipPosition++;
//if array exist its length remove callback
                    if (tipPosition == gritArray.length) {
                        gritInfoHanlder.removeCallbacks(this);
//delayed handler 10 sec
                    } else {
                        gritInfoHanlder.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 10);
                    }
                }
            });
```