# How to update TextView by infinitely looping through String Array values?

Tags: android, timer

I have created a string array in strings.xml with 5 strings. This is how I have initialized it:

```
adLoopValues = findViewById(R.id.ad_loop_values); // TextView
adValues = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.banner_ad_values);
```

Using the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31493878/4152581), I am looping through them:

```
final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adLoopValues.setText(adValues[i]);
            i++;
            if (i == adValues.length) {
                i = 0;
            } else {
                //5 sec
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 5);
            }
        }
});
```

The above code works for the first time, it shows first string in string array and then after 5 seconds shows the next one and goes to the last one. To loop it infinitely, I have put if block and reset i to 0 so after last string, it can again start from first value but that is not happening, after the last string is displayed, nothing happens. It doesn't start from first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't restart handler in

```
if (i == adValues.length) {
            i = 0;
        }
```

remove `else` and use `handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 5);` after `if` block

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have the delay and calculate the index with modulo.

```
final android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            adLoopValues.setText(adValues[i % addValues.length]);


            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000 * 5);
            i++;
        }
});
```