# Run Android Service every 30 seconds

Tags: android, service, intervals

I am creating a Notification using Android Service independent from UI. This works perfectly fine. Below is the code.

```
public class SendNotificationService extends Service {
    Context context;
    String test_heading;
    String test_body;

    final class notifThread implements Runnable {
        int service_id;

        notifThread(int service_id) {
            this.service_id = service_id;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String requested_method = "LoadBU";
            String bu_status = "1";

            CheckNewEntry checkNewEntry = new CheckNewEntry(SendNotificationService.this);
            checkNewEntry.execute(requested_method, bu_status);

            stopSelf(this.service_id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new notifThread(startId));
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications Stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This service also starts automatically on system boot. `CheckNewEntry` is my AsyncTask that checks the database and sends notification if there is any change. I have not added `CheckNewEntry` as it is beyond the scope of this question.

Now what I want to do is, run `CheckNewEntry` every 30 seconds or 1 minute.

Can anyone help?

Comment: use Handler method

Comment: Can you please modify my code as I am a newbie to Android Development? I have been trying to do so but failed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13423036/3395198

Comment: This is in fact what I am unable to understand. How to implement handler in my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820596/start-android-service-after-every-5-minutes

Comment: In best way use AlaramManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through different Stackoverflow questions/answers, I managed to come up with my own solution.

Below is the code that I have created and is working now.

```
    public class SendNotificationService extends Service {
    public Context context = this;
    public Handler handler = null;
    public static Runnable runnable = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String requested_method = "LoadBU";
                String bu_status = "1";

                CheckNewEntry checkNewEntry = new CheckNewEntry(SendNotificationService.this);
                checkNewEntry.execute(requested_method, bu_status);

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 15000);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications Stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

If anyone of you can provide a better solution, please do post.

Answer (score 0):

you can use handler like this.

```
public class SendNotificationService extends Service {
        Context context;
        String test_heading;
        String test_body;
        public static Runnable runn;
        public static Handler hand =new Handler();
        final class notifThread implements Runnable {
            int service_id;

            notifThread(int service_id) {
                this.service_id = service_id;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String requested_method = "LoadBU";
                String bu_status = "1";

                CheckNewEntry checkNewEntry = new CheckNewEntry(SendNotificationService.this);

     runn = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                     checkNewEntry.execute(requested_method, bu_status);

                    hand.postDelayed(runn, 30000);
                }
            };


            runn.run();


            stopSelf(this.service_id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new notifThread(startId));
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Notifications Stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am going to try it now.

Comment: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)

Comment: I preferred your answer, had it worked, as it is not changing my code much. But the answer that I figured out myself is also posted, which is working.